# Strange plane behavior in Unity3D while changing scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, undefined-behavior

I am a beginner with Unity3D.

Until now I have learned a few things.

For example, create a simple 2D menu, switch from one scene to another with an appropriate C# script and associate the scripts with the objects.

The problem I pose here is about the behavior (strange to me) of the white panel behind the menu when I change the scene.

I have two scenes, the first which is the menu and a second one is the actual game.

I used UI elements to create the first one,  while I used 3D objects to make the second one.

**So, what happens?**

It happens that when you step into the second scene by clicking on the green button the background becomes brown. If, on the other hand, I run the second scene individually without going through the first one (launching the scene directly), the background remains white.

[See this short video for further details](https://youtu.be/3n1Lud-HlgA).

Why?

---

> Listed below are some images, hoping they can help me understand my problem.

The first scene (dev mode):
[image]

The first scene (running):
[image]

The second scene (dev mode):
[image]

The second scene (running directly):
[image]

The second scene (running after clicking the green button "Comincia"):
[image]

The script I use to change the scene (linked to the green button):

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameScene : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void PlayNow () {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

---

> **Update**: I have updated the information on the application. I added a new screenshot where you can see the camera settings. Meanwhile, I changed some things, but the problem still remains. I also noticed that this problem only happens when I switch to the Game scene, when I switch to other scenes instead it does not.

Added a new screenshot showing the inspector of the Main Camera object:
[image]

Comment: This is probably related to some kind of setting in the inspector. There is no way the code you posted could have anything to do with it. I would start by checking the camera. There are setting in the camera, including one to show a static color as a background. Maybe that part is changing? If not, it's guesswork.

Comment: Thank you so much for your consideration, I'm working in the hope of being able to solve the problem. In the meantime I posted a new screenshot with the Main Camera information.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to understand where the problem was: I made an improper use of the Plane object (highlighted in the screenshot). By removing it, now it shows correctly the solid color white background as set on the Main Camera.

[image]